# Display database records in jTextField

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, jtextfield

I want to display some questions and their answers. So to test that I just tried to display the question number and the question but there's

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

error and I don't know what to do next. 
1. I want to display next record with the next button.
2. seteditable isn't working (giving error)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String qid=jTextField1.setEditable(false);
String qid=jTextField1.getText();
String ques=jTextField2.getText();

 try{       
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1","root","");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from qc where qid=1");                          
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("qid"));
                jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("ques"));
            }
            }           
            catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
            {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
}                                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, that you have a MySql-Driver in your classpath.

You can download it here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Configuring your classpath is dependent on your environment. If you are running your code from within eclipse you can follow these steps:

1. Download jdbc driver
2. Put jdbc driver (for example `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`) into your eclipse project
3. Rightclick on it, `Build Path`, `Add to Build Path`

Using netbeans:

1. Download jdbc driver
2. Put jdbc driver (for example `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`) into your netbeans project
3. Right click on project, *Properties*, go to *Libraries*, choose *Run-time libraries*
4. Add the jar to the list

---

For jumping to the next item, there are several options.

One solution could look like this:

Add this code at the top of your class:

```
// private JTextField jTextField1;
// private JTextField jTextField2;
// ...
private int currentQid; // add this line to declare a new field of type int
```

Then inside your actionlistener method:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM qc WHERE qid > ? ORDER BY qid LIMIT 1");
ps.setInt(1, currentQid);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
    currentQid = rs.getInt("qid");
    jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(currentQid));
    jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("ques"));
}
```

In detail:

- `SELECT * FROM qc WHERE qid > ? ORDER BY qid LIMIT 1` will select the record, with the qid next to `?`
- `ps.setInt(1, currentQid);` will set the first parameter of the query (the `?`) to a provided value
- `currentQid = rs.getInt("qid");` will save the next qid in the instance field `currentQid`
- `Integer.toString(currentQid)` will convert `currentQid` to a text
- `jTextField1.setText(...);` will display the text inside of `jTextField1`

Comment: sir ! I am using Netbeans. How to do that in Netbeans

Comment: @abhinavsingh I added a description for netbeans. I don't have netbeans installed currently, so the description might be slightly inaccurate - but it gives you an idea how to solve that issue.

Comment: thank you sir ! it worked.
But I still have a problem: i want to display next record on button click. Can you help ?

Comment: @abhinavsingh I updated my answer. It's just an idea - I haven't actually tried it out. But it might help you finding a solution.

Comment: I think that TOP 1 is specific for sql server

Comment: @Win.ubuntu true! I changed it to "LIMIT 1"

Comment: `run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""   
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.....`

Comment: @abhinavsingh I updated my answer. It is now less *quick and dirty* and should not give `NumberFormatException`s anymore. Thanks for marking my answer as accepted!